# SQLAlchemy autocommiting?

Tags: python, transactions, sqlalchemy

I have an issue with SQLAlchemy apparently committing.  A rough sketch of my code:

```
trans = self.conn.begin()
try:            
    assert not self.conn.execute(my_obj.__table__.select(my_obj.id == id)).first()
    self.conn.execute(my_obj.__table__.insert().values(id=id))
    assert not self.conn.execute(my_obj.__table__.select(my_obj.id == id)).first()
except:
    trans.rollback()
    raise
```

I don't commit, and the second assert always fails!  In other words, it seems the data is getting inserted into the database even though the code is within a transaction!  Is this assessment accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in that changes aren't get *commited* to DB. But they are auto-*flushed* by SQLAlchemy when you perform query, in your case flush is performed on lines with asserts. So if you will not explicitly call `commit` you will never see these changes in DB, within real data. However, you will get them back as long as you use the same `conn` object.

You can pass `autoflush=False` to session constructor do disable this behavior.