# Make SQLAlchemy COMMIT instead of ROLLBACK after a SELECT query

Tags: python, postgresql, transactions, sqlalchemy, commit

I am developing an app together with a partner. I do the database part in PostgreSQL, my partner implements the app on the web-server with Python using SQLAlchemy. We make heavy use of server-side functions. A `SELECT` query on one of those looks like this in the DB log:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;

SELECT col_a, col_b FROM some_func(E'myvalue');

ROLLBACK;
```

In the functions I write certain input to a log table. The app queries by `SELECT`, SQLAlchemy only sees a `SELECT` statement and insists on a `ROLLBACK`. Logging fails. I need it to `COMMIT` instead. My partner claims there is no easy way, we would have to remove SQLAlchemy altogether. I think he must be wrong but lack the knowledge to claim otherwise.

Is there an easy way to make SQLAlchemy `COMMIT` instead of `ROLLBACK`?
What keeps me from just executing `trans.commit()`? Do I need to set `autoflush=False` for that?

I have scanned the [FAQ](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/index.html), but did not find an answer there.
Searching SO revealed some related questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4393035/939860) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2432527/939860), but I am not in the clear.
Maybe this [recipe](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/DisableAutoflush) would work?

Comment: Are you sure that sqlalchemy is really the one responsible for the rollback?  Could it be that you are using a framework that automatically rolls back uncommited sessions at the end of a request loop?

Comment: Not entirely sure, I'll have to ask my partner. I think [psychopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/) is in use. But in that case, couldn't we just `COMMIT` to keep the framework from rolling back?

Comment: It should be enough to either explicitly commit the isolating transaction or set isolation level to zero.

Comment: What I'm asking is if you're using an application framework like Pylons or Zope that in some way manages database state for you;  Are you using only sqlalchemy in a plain ol' python script?  Just how is the lifetime of each `Session` instance managed?

Comment: It would be great if you could post the corresponding code of your partner with SA usage. My first guess would be that the *session.commit()* is not even called, and the rollback comes from the connection pool management to ensure clean connection for new request.

Comment: I will ask my partner to have a look here and provide the missing info.

Comment: I am sorry, my partner refuses to cooperate. Nothing that can be solved on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using SQLAlchemy's connection pooling, then what you're seeing is probably the automatic rollback that happens when a connection is closed after use.  It's apparently necessary to guarantee that the connection is 'clean' for the next time it's pulled out of the pool.  See [this page](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/connections.html) for more info; search for 'pooling mechanism' near the top.

From what I recall (it's been a couple years since I last worked with this) changing the isolation level to autocommit won't solve the problem, since it won't see the SELECT statement as requiring a commit.

You really just want to wrap that statement in a transaction.  I don't know how your code is structured, but you should just be able to use SQLAlchemy's connection.begin and connection.commit.  You could even just execute the BEGIN and COMMIT as arbitrary SQL.