# I'm getting a 'ghost' ROLLBACK from sqlalchemy but not when use psql with postgres

Tags: python, transactions, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.2

I have a weird behaviour with postgres + sqlalchemy.

I call a function that insert into a table, but when called from sqlalchemy it roolback at the end, and when called from psql it succeed:

Logs when called by sqlalchemy (as reported by the logs):

```
Jan 21 13:17:28 intersec.local postgres[3466]: [18-9] STATEMENT:  SELECT name, suffix 
Jan 21 13:17:28 intersec.local postgres[3466]: [18-10]  FROM doc_codes('195536d95bd155b9ea412154b3e920761495681a')
Jan 21 13:17:28 intersec.local postgres[3466]: [19-9] STATEMENT:  ROLLBACK
Jan 21 13:17:28 intersec.local postgres[3465]: [13-9] STATEMENT:  COMMIT
```

If using psql:

```
Jan 21 13:28:47 intersec.local postgres[3561]: [20-9] STATEMENT:  SELECT name, suffix FROM doc_codes('195536d95bd155b9ea412154b3e920761495681a');
```

Note not transaction stuff at all.

This is my python code:

```
def getCon(self):
    conStr = "postgresql+psycopg2://%(USER)s:%(PASSWORD)s@%(HOST)s/%(NAME)s"
    config = settings.DATABASES['default']
    #print conStr % config
    con = sq.create_engine(
        conStr % config,
        echo=ECHO
    )

    event.listen(con, 'checkout', self.set_path)

    self.con = con
    self.meta.bind = con

    return con

def getDocPrefixes(self, deviceId):
    f = sq.sql.func.doc_codes(deviceId, type_=types.String)

    columns = [
        sq.Column('name', types.String),
        sq.Column('suffix', types.String)
    ]

    return [dict(x.items()) for x in self.con.execute
            (
                select(columns).
                select_from(f)
            ).fetchall()]

sync = dbSync('malab')
for k in sync.getDocPrefixes('195536d95bd155b9ea412154b3e920761495681a'):
    print k['name'], '=', k['suffix']
```

What could trigger the ROLLBACK?

P.D: My DB functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION next_letter (
  table_name TEXT,
  OUT RETURNS TEXT
)
AS
$$
DECLARE
    result TEXT = 'A';
    nextLetter TEXT;
    num INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO num nextval('letters');
    nextLetter := chr(num);
    result := nextLetter;

    WHILE true LOOP
        --RAISE NOTICE '%', result;
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DocPrefix WHERE Name=result AND TableName=table_name) THEN
            SELECT max(SUBSTRING(name FROM '\d+'))
                FROM DocPrefix WHERE Name=result AND TableName=table_name
                INTO num;

            result := nextLetter || (coalesce(num,0) + 1);
        ELSE
            EXIT;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURNS = result;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

-- Retorna el prefijo unico para la tabla/dispositivo.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prefix_fordevice (
  table_name TEXT,
  device_id TEXT,
  OUT RETURNS TEXT
)
AS
$$
DECLARE
    result TEXT = NULL;
    row RECORD;
BEGIN
    IF NOT(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DocPrefix WHERE MachineId=device_id AND TableName=table_name)) THEN
        INSERT INTO DocPrefix
            (Name, MachineId, TableName)
        VALUES
            (next_letter(table_name),  device_id, table_name);
    END IF;

    SELECT name FROM DocPrefix WHERE
        MachineId=device_id AND TableName=table_name
    INTO result;

    RETURNS =  result;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

--Retornar los prefijos exclusivos para el ID de dispositvo
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION doc_codes(device_id TEXT) RETURNS TABLE("name" TEXT, "suffix" TEXT) AS $$
    SELECT name, prefix_fordevice(name,  device_id) AS suffix FROM doccode;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer here:

[Make SQLAlchemy COMMIT instead of ROLLBACK after a SELECT query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559570/make-sqlalchemy-commit-instead-of-rollback-after-a-select-query?rq=1)

```
def getDocPrefixes(self, deviceId):
    f = sq.sql.func.doc_codes(deviceId, type_=types.String)

    columns = [
        sq.Column('name', types.String),
        sq.Column('sufix', types.String)
    ]

    with self.con.begin():
        return [dict(x.items()) for x in self.con.execute
            (
                select(columns).
                select_from(f)
            ).fetchall()]
```

The thing is, the function can insert data + also return a SELECT, so, sqlalchemy think this is a normal SELECT when in fact the function also change data and need commit.

Answer (score 2):

the antipattern here is that you're confusing a SQLAlchemy `Engine` for a connection, when you do something like this:

```
con = sq.create_engine(<url>)
result = con.execute(statement)
```

the Engine is associated with a connection pool as a source of connections.  When you call the execute() method on Engine, it checks out a connection from the pool, runs the statement, and returns the results; when the result set is exhausted, it returns the connection to the pool.  At that stage, the pool will either close the connection fully, or it will re-pool it.  Storing the connection in the pool means that any remaining transactional state must be cleared (note that DBAPI connections are *always in a transaction* when they are used), so it emits a rollback.

Your program should create a single `Engine` per URL at the module level, and when it needs a connection, should call upon `engine.connect()`.

the document [Working with Engines and Connections](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/connections.html) explains all of this.

Comment: Ok, I now put the create engine outside the class. Then ask for con.connect() for getCon. However, still see the same thing. Then switch to NullPool, also the same. This is running inside a django app..

Comment: I check and run this outside django. The same results, so is not related to django..

Comment: well if you are doing a statement that needs to commit, and its a stored procedure, SQLA's autocommit won't recognize that.  so yes, you need to run begin() as you did above, or use autocommit.  once again, this is all in the document I linked - autocommit specifically: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit